# Please tell me why an empty array is written to the variables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, web

```
$January = $articles->whereMonth('updated_at','01')
  ->whereYear('updated_at', $year)
  ->get();

$February = $articles->whereMonth('updated_at','02')
  ->whereYear('updated_at', $year)
  ->get();
```

If there is no data in `$January`, then an empty array is written to `$February` regardless of the data availability. Tell me how to fix it and why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572686/ive-assigned-laravel-query-builder-to-a-variable-it-changes-when-being-used) answered before

you need to use `clone` on `$articles` like this :

```
$January = (clone $articles)->whereMonth('updated_at','01')
  ->whereYear('updated_at', $year)
  ->get();

$February = (clone $articles)->whereMonth('updated_at','02')
  ->whereYear('updated_at', $year)
  ->get();
```