# Laravel - How to clone from a model with all its criteria

Tags: php, laravel, model, criteria

I have a variable that contains a model and I want to duplicate it with all its criteria to another variable.

```
$modelOne = ModelOne::where('column_one', 'value_one');

if($condition_one) {
    $modelOne = $modelOne->where('column_two', 'value_two');
}
```

... and many other if conditions ...

```
$modelTwo = $modelOne;
```

The problem starts from here that when I add another `where` to `$modelTwo`, the `$modelOne` is affected either.

for example when I do `$modelTwo->where('specific_column', 'specific_value')`, the `$modelOne` will be limited by the `where` set for `$modelTwo`.

How can I separate their `where`s?

Comment: this question answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572686/ive-assigned-laravel-query-builder-to-a-variable-it-changes-when-being-used

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the PHP `clone` keyword:

```
$modelOne = ModelOne::where('column_one', 'value_one');
// ...

$modelTwo = clone $modelOne;
// changes to $modelTwo should not affect $modelOne anymore
```

The eloquent builder internally implements the `__clone` magic method to also clone the internal query builder